# Permission denied while running a .jar file

Tags: permissions, java

When I was launching a .jar file it says `Permission denied`.

```
Error while launching

java./io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/crusty/.illenium/jdk/jre1.8.0_291/li/javaws.jar":
error=13, Permission denied
```

I have tried to give it all the permissions by changing javaws.jar from read-only to read and write. I have also checkmarked *Allow executing file as a program* in *Properties* -> *Permissions*, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: You installed Java wrong, re-install java as outlined on https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-jre

Answer (score 0):

You installed Java the wrong way. To resolve the `permission denied` error message install openjdk-8-jre from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt upgrade  
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

Select the openjdk-8-jre that you just installed as the default Java version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

At the command prompt that appears after running `sudo update-alternatives --config java` press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: